how to run tests using different db connection
I would like to run tests on a db different from the real one. So I cloned the real db into a new one and tried wpdb::select passing as second parameter a mysqli connection to test db.
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3308", 'user', 'pass', 'mydb'); 
   
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} else {
    $wpdb->select('mydb', $mysqli);
    $product = new \WC_Product();
    $product->set_name( "Product Test 1" );
    $product->set_slug( "product-test-1" );
    $product->set_regular_price( 100.00 ); 
    $product->set_stock_status( "instock" );
    $product->save();

But the product is created on the real db. So I would like to know how I can hit the test db during tests using wp functions like get_posts and WP_Query and WC_Product::save.

Changing the DB connection used by a WPDB object that already exists or passing it a mysqli instance is not possible.
And if it was, it still wouldn't work for other reasons.
if you want to access a new database connection you need to create a new WPDB instance:
$second_db = new WPDB( 'dbuser', 'dbpassword', 'dbname', 'dbhost' );

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/__construct/
This leads you to a second fundamental problem though, for tests to work you need a clean slate, you can't switch the DB halfway through a request to test something in a second DB.

$wpdb still exists and any APIs you call would fetch data from the first database, and write to it.
If you replace $wpdb somehow you face a more insidious problem that WordPress pre-fetches and caches a lot of data in advance, leading to mismatched data from different databases

If you're going to do this properly, there are much better ways to write tests that do support using a second database, aka the WP Unit test framework and PHPUnit, for details on that see the Testing chapter of the WordPress Core handbook on wordpress.org

"there are much better ways to write tests that do support using a second database, aka the WP Unit test framework and PHPUnit" - a link to some documentation would be useful here, or a more detailed explanation.

It's the official test system that WordPress uses and mentioned in the official testing handbook on wordress.org, here's the section on databases: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/automated-testing/writing-phpunit-tests/#database it creates a new database out of the box, so it's more effort not to use a separate DB than it is to use the same one

Ah, it was on my reading list, but not read yet. From a quick skim, it's still sparse on how everything is connected, but if you follow the setup instructions, it's taken care of behind the scenes.
From my own digging, the test suite loads a separate config file, skipping the usual wp-config.php, does a bunch of other prep, then boots WP as usual via wp-settings.php.

Following the example of the official WP test suite, if for whatever reason you don't want to use that test suite, then the way to go is:

Create a separate wp-tests-config.php, pointing at the separate test DB.
Have your tests load this wp-tests-config.php.
Boot up WP by loading wp-settings.php.

This can be done from the tests' bootstrap code, or you can load wp-settings.php at the end of the wp-tests-config.php, and point phpunit.xml directly at wp-tests-config.php as the bootstrap file.
Do not use wp-load.php, as that would try to load your non-testing wp-config.php, and end up using the non-testing DB.
However, you may as well just use the official test suite.
